# MultiItemCarousel working on CodePen and not on jsfiddle

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel, jsfiddle, codepen

Hi i was creating a multi item carousel with infinite loop.I have seen code that are encoded on Codepen but when i tried it inside my work and jsfiddle it seems not getting the result on the code pen. My goal is like the result the codepen is showing but the result i get on my work was the result on jsfiddle i would like to seek advice what was wrong why is it not getting result on the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/7zhvn59o/2/

https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY

```
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- add  more items here -->
          <!-- Example item start:  -->

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>

          <!--  Example item end -->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    // Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});


    .multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
      transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }
  .carouse-control{
    &.left, &.right{
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}

// non-related styling:
body{
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i copy pasted the code from codepen and added bootstrap and jquery cdn link and it worked. below is the link for your reference . thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/vfL0sn8z/`777`

Comment: Can i ask how for future reference sorry for incovenience

Comment: i tried it on my self and still not working is it bootstrap 4.1.3 and jquery 3.3.1?

Comment: you had not added bootstrap and jquery link. add your code in jsfiddle and codepen was not same.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pynechan/rpLa4suq/ sorry wrong link, this one i tried the bootstrap version that we are using but it seems not displaying correct

Comment: you javascript section is showing `no-library` whereas if you check mine. it will show jquery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pynechan/rpLa4suq/14/ i added jquery 3.3.1 same ..is it the problem because i got bootstrap 4 instead of 3?

Comment: yes. the structure in bootstrap 3 and 4 is different

Comment: In your opinion is nit because i'm using bootstrap 4 that's why i don't produce same result. because i needed this kind of carousel :'( that uses bootstrap 4

Comment: there is lot of difference in bootstrap 3 and 4 like class names are changed, html structure, in bootstrap 4 now they are using flexbox. so might because of that. when i changed it to bootstrap 3 it worked. if you try to migrate a website from bootstrap 3 to 4 then you will find that there will be some change in the ui. hope this helped you. thanks